# Ideal README file for Web applications

Tags: ruby-on-rails, django, documentation, markdown, project-organization

I am kind of obsessed with how I document and organize my projects. I am curious about best practices for readme files, and looking to learn more about what should be in it. I am mostly using rails. But I believe that readme should make no assumptions about the reader and explain everything with from scratch. So what would be your ideal descriptive timeless readme file for web application projects? Also It would ve very helpful if you attach the readme files you like.

content? short info the about app? language, framework? screenshot? format? markdown vs plain? ideal deployment? etc..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to write a good README](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2304863/how-to-write-a-good-readme)?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't make assumptions about the reader then plain text is the best choice. Any markup language needs to be parsed and converted which may not be possible when viewing the readme locally. Sites such as Github support various markup formats which is good but you're limited to what they support.

It terms of content: it should explain everything that the user would possibly want to do, such as compile, build, run, modify, et cetera.